# Appending HTML element with Javascript, element isn't seen?

Tags: javascript, html, http, callback

I'm still new to javascript, so expect to see a lot of bad programming practices...

```js
function addButton(name, state) {
    numButtons += 1;
    if (name === '') {
        var i = 0;
        while(buttonStates.hasOwnProperty("button" + i) === true) i++;
        name = "button" + i;
    }
    document.getElementById("buttonTable").innerHTML +=
        "<tr>\
            <td>\
                <p id=\"buttonName" + numButtons + "\" class=\"buttonName\">" + name + "</p>\
            </td><td>\
                <button id=\"" + name + "\" onclick=\"setButton(this, 'toggle')\" class=\"button\">OFF</button>\
            </td>\
        </tr>";
//===IMPORTANT AREA 1==========================================================//
    //setTimeout(function(){setButton(document.getElementById(name), state)}, 0); //works
    setButton(document.getElementById(name), state); //doesn't work, no change
//=============================================================================//
}

    function setButton(elem, state) {
        //this is where the button's colors are set to light colors
        //notice how I am using elem.style.backgroundColor
        if(String(state) === 'toggle') state = !buttonStates[elem.id];
        if (String(state) === 'true') {
            buttonStates[elem.id] = true;
            elem.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(112,192,112)";
            elem.textContent = 'ON';
        } else {
            buttonStates[elem.id] = false;
            elem.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,128,128)";
            elem.textContent = 'OFF';
        }
        
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    //===IMPORTANT AREA 2==========================================================//
                if (buttonStates[elem.id] === true) {
                    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; //doesn't work, no change. Notice how I am, again, using elem.style.backgroundColor
                    //document.getElementById(elem.id).style.backgroundColor = 'green'; //works
                } else {
                    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                }
  //=============================================================================//
            } else {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "readyState: " + this.readyState + "<br>status: " + this.status;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "/buttonToggle", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(elem.id + "=" + buttonStates[elem.id]);
    }
```

So basically I add an HTML button in addButton(), which calls setButton() and passes the new element to that function. In setButton(), it first sets the element's color to light-green or light-red, indicating that the server has not yet updated the state of the button. This part works fine, the button's color DOES change. HOWEVER, in the callback function for the server request, the button refuses to change color in the exact same method as used before. I have found ways around it (either by using setTimeout() with a time of 0ms, or by using the passed element to again get the element from document), but I want to know WHY this happens. It seems to only be a problem in the callback function. I have verified that the callback function does execute and that the code for changing the color is executed.

As a side note, if I have multiple buttons, the last button works fine and all those before it do not work, their color is still light-green or light-red.
[Notice buttons 0-5 are all a light color, yet button6 is solid, WHY?!?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7s5E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Different elements on the HTML doc should have different unique ids. Your all buttons have the same id so only last one is working.

Make your ids unique by using `'button' + i` like you are using name.

Comment: Is that not what I am doing here?
<button id=\"" + name + "\" onclick=\"setButton(this, 'toggle')\" class=\"button\">OFF</button>\

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don´t get the current error and why your code doesn´t work. Maybe we need to see the whole code?

But you are definitely searching for the keyword "event loop".
When your code works when you are running it in a timeout, your code needs to be running async.
See more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

If you post the whole code, I will take a look again, but maybe this already helps.
And if this are your first steps in programming, you are doing it great!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2t96Rw6h
This may also help, but after logging the beginning and end of the callback function, i get this:
Before: button0 rgb(112, 192, 112)
After:  button0 green ... This pattern is repeated all the way through button6, so I know it IS changing the color, but HTML does not update button0-5?